Google spreadsheets "VLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range."
I can't seem to get VLOOKUP to work on google spreadsheet.

To my understanding, it should search for c, then return the value on the column to the right since index=2. I will note that when I plug in index=1 it returns c with no error. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

You are doing wrong in lookup array part. You are passing N2:N5 which is 1 column but your trying to get result from column 2. So it would-
=VLOOKUP(P2,N2:O5,2,TRUE)


Ah!! Thanks. I missed that in the search range one also needs to include the column of the results. Isn't this a bit weird? What would happen if there is a c in the right column?

@Guy That is actually VLOOKUP() work. If C exist in right column it will not affect searching because vlookup() only search in first column of search range and return result from other column. I will suggest you to use XLOOKUP() instead of VLOOKUP(). You may try=XLOOKUP(P2,N2:N5,O2:O5).

Ok, got it. Thanks.
